# Cannot override onDialogClosed in androidx.listPreference , any examples to solve this?

Tags: android, androidx, listpreference

The method "onDialogClosed" which was part of listPreference has been removed from androidx.
As a part of migrating my project to androidx. I cannot override onDialogClosed for listPreference.

```
                ListPreference lp = new ListPreference(this) {

                @Override
                protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)
                {
                    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
                    if(positiveResult) {
                        .......
                    }
                }
            };
```

error :method cannot be overridden.